# Python for .NET: passing List<dynamic> to C# function

Tags: c#, python, python.net

I'm trying to call from python code C# functions from a dll using Python for .NET. Most things worked out of the box or I could figure them out from other posts (like passing an IntPtr from an array below), but the last thing that refuses to work is to pass a list as a parameter.

Here's the C# function

`bool CalculateResult(string resultName, IntPtr resultArray, IList <dynamic> AuxParameters = null)`

and how it's used in an example C# code snippet:

`CalculateResult("xyz", ptr, new List<dynamic> { 50 });`

I do succeed calling the function from python WITHOUT the optional 3rd parameter:

```
clr.AddReference('SDK')
import SDK_Namespace
from System import Array, Int16, IntPtr, String
from System.Runtime.InteropServices import GCHandle, GCHandleType

pyArr = [0] * 100
csArr = Array[Int16](pyArr )
arr_hndl = GCHandle.Alloc(csArr, GCHandleType.Pinned)
ptr_arr = arr_hndl.AddrOfPinnedObject()
CalculateResult(result, ptr_arr)
# pyArr has now values, yay!
```

Now, if I try to do the same WITH an additional list parameter I fail what ever I try:

```
from System.Collections.Generic import List

pyList = [50]
CalculateResult(result, ptr_arr, pyList)
# TypeError: No method matches given arguments for CalculateResult
CalculateResult.__overloads__[String, IntPtr, List](result, ptr_arr, pyList)
# TypeError: No match found for signature

csList = List[Int16]()
csList.Add(50)
CalculateResult(result, ptr_arr, csList)
# TypeError: No method matches given arguments for CalculateResult
CalculateResult.__overloads__[String, IntPtr, List](result, ptr_arr, csList)
# TypeError: No match found for signature
```

What am I missing and how can I make this work?

**Edit**

Following Jeroen's comment and reading up on [boxing and unboxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) I was able to run the C# function as below:

```
from System import Object
par = int(50)
csList = List[Object]()
csList.Add(Object(par))
CalculateResult(result, ptr_arr, csList)
```

Now the function threw an exception without much of a hint for debugging.

However, another function `GetInfo(string resultName, IList <dynamic> AuxParameters = null)` with similar arguments was more helpful telling me:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type
'object' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at SDK.GetInfo(String ResultName, IList`1 Parameters)
```

As I can't change anything on the C# side where I suspect the unboxing must happen the question changes to:

Is there anything I can still do to perform the 'explicit conversion' or do I have to give up?

Comment: A generic type parameterized with `dynamic` is functionally the same as having it parameterized with `object`, and that's how it appears in metadata. The difference is only in how the compiled code accesses the object (through dynamic binding). The correct type on the IL level for the method is `IList<object>`, and a scalar array would need to be converted to an array of boxed value types first. (I have no idea what the Python code then needs to look like, but that's what your problem reduces to.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this works in your case, but I was able to make a call using this in Python (with the Python for .NET extension):

```
xl = List[Object]()
xl.Add(50)
b = d.CalculateResult("resultName", ptr_arr, xl)
```

The object that shows up in the C# method is of type `Int32`, which is probably what is expected.

I implemented a test method with the same signature as yours, this is what I used:

```
public bool CalculateResult(string resultName, IntPtr resultArray, IList<dynamic> AuxParameters = null)
{
    if (AuxParameters != null)
    {
        dynamic a = AuxParameters.First();
        Console.WriteLine(" *Type: " + ((object)a).GetType().Name);
        foreach (var m in ((object)a).GetType().GetMembers())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" " + m.Name);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I swear this option was among my 150 brute force attempts, but I guess at the time something else was off... Thanks, the code is doing now all it's supposed to do! BTW, it also works for `xl.Add(Int32(somePyInt))`

Comment: I thought so, your examples were quite close ;-) Int32 is the default type for integers, which is used by Python for .NET as well. Depending on what your function actually does, it might not work for other integer types (e.g. Int16). Good to hear it works now!